# iOS - Capture data when shutter fires

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, gyroscope

Is there an easy way to capture gyroscope at the exact time the shutter is fired on the camera? I am currently using the IUImagePickerController and I can't find an easy way to interrupt or tie into the image taking process.

Comment: do you need more details about the image than what is given in the picture's metadata??

Comment: Yes. I would like to pull GPS coords, compass direction, and a gyroscope reading. I don't believe that gyro or compass information is stored in metadata. If it is, please enlighten me.

Comment: Are you stuck with UIImagePickerController? The lower-level camera APIs give more access to timing information.

Comment: I am not stuck with UIImagePickerController. It's just what I stumbled across first. Can you give me a couple of class names for the lower-level camera APIs that you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The closest you'll be able to do is implement:

`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:`

and save the gps coords and gyro at that time. However its not fired the instance that the shutter is fired but it should be very close. If I were you I recommend just saving GPS location, not the gyro. Not only is it hard to reproduce, but also you wont have the elevation which would change the picture. (ie: if your taking the shot from a skyscrapper.) Also make sure you enable the GPS BEFORE you start the camera so that theres no delay/ask the user for permission.